# Firefox freezing with css transform

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, transform

I am trying to make this animation `http://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/zxRwWx` cross browser however it seems that firefox isn't accepting it for some reasons. It's freezing once the mouse is moving and even the keyframe animation isn't working. Strangely even IE display it at some extend which makes me wonder if the problem isn't coming from the JS iself rather than CSS but I can't see anything wrong in this code that would make mozilla specificly freeze.

```js
const sentence = document.querySelector('.sentence')
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2')

let wordsToArray = (str) => str.split('').map(e => e === ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : e)

function insertSpan(elem, letters, startTime) {
  elem.textContent = ''
  let curr = 0
  let delay = 20
  for(let letter of letters) {
    let span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = letter
    span.style.animationDelay = (++curr / delay + (startTime || 0)) + 's'
    elem.appendChild(span)
  }
}

insertSpan(h1, wordsToArray(h1.textContent))
insertSpan(h2, wordsToArray(h2.textContent), .5)

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {  
  let xpos = e.layerX || e.offsetX
  let ypos = e.layerY || e.offsetY
  
  let ax = -(window.innerWidth / 2 - xpos) / 20
  let ay = (window.innerHeight / 2 - ypos) / 10
  
  sentence.style.transform = `rotateY(${ax}deg) rotateX(${ay}deg)`
})
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F0544F;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

body, .container, .sentence {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 30em;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -2em -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,.4)));
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sentence {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    will-change: transform;
    animation: animation 2s linear infinite alternate;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  h2 {
    font-weight: thin;
  }
}

// psssst! http://bouncejs.com/
@keyframes animation { 
  0% { transform: matrix3d(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.19514, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.19514, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -3.8179, 0, 1); }
  3.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.48061, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.48061, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -16.89184, 0, 1); }
  5% { transform: matrix3d(0.78868, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.78868, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -35.82897, 0, 1); }
  6.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.06298, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06298, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -54.24398, 0, 1); }
  8.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.26541, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.26541, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -67.42532, 0, 1); }
  10% { transform: matrix3d(1.37835, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.37835, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -73.79667, 0, 1); }
  11.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.40302, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.40302, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -74.15221, 0, 1); }
  13.333333% {  opacity: 1; transform: matrix3d(1.35507, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.35507, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -70.32855, 0, 1); }
  15% { transform: matrix3d(1.25874, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.25874, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -64.25506, 0, 1); }
  16.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.14088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -57.53621, 0, 1); }
  18.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.02595, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02595, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -51.35907, 0, 1); }
  20% { transform: matrix3d(0.93241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.93241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -46.51039, 0, 1); }
  21.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.87106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.87106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -43.40452, 0, 1); }
  23.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.84491, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84491, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -42.11433, 0, 1); }
  25% { transform: matrix3d(0.85043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.85043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -42.42524, 0, 1); }
  26.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.87962, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.87962, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -43.92027, 0, 1); }
  28.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.92232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.92232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -46.08478, 0, 1); }
  30% { transform: matrix3d(0.96839, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.96839, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -48.40959, 0, 1); }
  31.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00942, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00942, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.47334, 0, 1); }
  33.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.0397, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0397, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -51.99258, 0, 1); }
  35% { transform: matrix3d(1.05659, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05659, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -52.83794, 0, 1); }
  36.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.06028, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06028, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -53.02083, 0, 1); }
  38.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.05311, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05311, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -52.65993, 0, 1); }
  40% { transform: matrix3d(1.0387, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0387, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -51.93743, 0, 1); }
  41.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.02107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -51.05459, 0, 1); }
  43.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.19419, 0, 1); }
  45% { transform: matrix3d(0.98989, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98989, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.4943, 0, 1); }
  46.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.98072, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98072, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.03539, 0, 1); }
  48.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.9768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -48.83983, 0, 1); }
  50% { transform: matrix3d(0.97763, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97763, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -48.88146, 0, 1); }
  51.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.98199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.09973, 0, 1); }
  53.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.98838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98838, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.41905, 0, 1); }
  55% { transform: matrix3d(0.99527, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99527, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.76363, 0, 1); }
  56.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.07044, 0, 1); }
  58.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00594, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00594, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.29687, 0, 1); }
  60% { transform: matrix3d(1.00846, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00846, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.4232, 0, 1); }
  61.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00902, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00902, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.4508, 0, 1); }
  63.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00794, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00794, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.39716, 0, 1); }
  65% { transform: matrix3d(1.00579, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00579, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.28941, 0, 1); }
  66.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00315, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00315, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.15758, 0, 1); }
  68.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.02902, 0, 1); }
  70% { transform: matrix3d(0.99849, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99849, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.9244, 0, 1); }
  71.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.99712, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99712, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.85578, 0, 1); }
  73.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.99653, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99653, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.82653, 0, 1); }
  75% { transform: matrix3d(0.99665, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99665, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.8327, 0, 1); }
  76.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.99731, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99731, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.86535, 0, 1); }
  78.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.99826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.91311, 0, 1); }
  80% { transform: matrix3d(0.99929, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99929, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.96465, 0, 1); }
  81.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00021, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00021, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.01054, 0, 1); }
  83.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.0444, 0, 1); }
  85% { transform: matrix3d(1.00127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.0633, 0, 1); }
  86.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.06743, 0, 1); }
  88.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.0594, 0, 1); }
  90% { transform: matrix3d(1.00087, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00087, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.04329, 0, 1); }
  91.666667% { transform: matrix3d(1.00047, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00047, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.02357, 0, 1); }
  93.333333% { transform: matrix3d(1.00009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50.00434, 0, 1); }
  95% { transform: matrix3d(0.99977, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99977, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.98869, 0, 1); }
  96.666667% { transform: matrix3d(0.99957, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99957, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.97843, 0, 1); }
  98.333333% { transform: matrix3d(0.99948, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99948, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -49.97405, 0, 1); }
  100% {  opacity: 1; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -50, 0, 1); } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sentence">
    <h1> Yay! Jelly text </h1>
    <h2> move your mouse around </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: looks a little bit like your prefixer is not working. did you call your js on document ready?

Comment: @Doml The-Bread No it isn't called on document ready (afaik), however the JS is handling the 3D which is working but freezing like crazy. I am not sure about the prefixer but I am guessing it should work since it's codepen ?

Comment: @Doml The-Bread I just tried locally with prepos and the problem remain so I think autoprefix isn't responsible for it.

Comment: I am running it with FF 50 and can't reproduce the issue anymore.